# sufficient conditions for: homogeneous polynomial non-negative for $x\geq0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Are there any sufficient conditions, s.t. a homogeneous polynomial with real coefficients (of degree $m$ in $n$ variables) is non-negative for all $x\in\mathbb R^n$ with $x\geq0$?

$x\geq0$ here means that all entries of $x$ are non-negative.

(Changed my question.)

Comment: Nope, counterexample $x^2-xy+y^2$.

Comment: Thanks! Are there weaker sufficient conditions, s.t. the polynomial is non-negative for all $x\geq0$?

Comment: Sorry, no idea.

Comment: Can't believe I asked this question, I just realized that for any symmetric matrix with real coefficients with nonnegative eigenvalues I'll get a counterexample with it's induced polynomial (interpreting it as a quadratic form). But still intrested in sufficient conditions, maybe I should ask a new question.

Comment: *If it has negative entries. Like in your example $\begin{matrix} 1 && -0.5 \\ -0.5 && 1\end{matrix}$.